# How to access __len__() hook method inside of python class?

Tags: python

I've googled, but I couldn't find a solution to this. And I'm not even sure if this is "a Pythonic way to do it".

Let's take a simple example:

```
class Simple():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_data = [1, 2, 3]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.my_data)

    def new_method(self):
        pass
        # -> How to access the __len__() method here
```

How can I access the `len()` method in `new_method` (**inside** the class)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `len()` with an instance of `Simple` as parameter

```
s = Simple()
print(len(s)) # 3
```

Inside the class you can use `self` as the instance

```
def new_method(self):
    print(len(self))
```

Comment: I'd like to call it inside the class, not outside of it.